# Unable to bind input field data in model array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

When I enter a value in the input field, I cannot bind the value in the model array and  unable to access in `$scope.selectfield[$index]`.

Here is the part of Html code:

```js
var ap = angular.module("myapp", []);
ap.controller("membercontroller", function($scope, $http, $window) {
  $scope.selectfield = [];

  $scope.dropdown = ["abc", "xyz", "pq", "aqz"];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="membercontroller">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <label id="billamt"> Select Members:</label>
    <div class="dropdown">
    
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="checkbox" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- expanded="true">
        Select members
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li ng-repeat="z in dropdown">
          <a href="#">
            {{z}}
            <br>
            <input type="number" ng-model="selectfield[$index]" value="{{selectfield[$index]}}"/>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

$index is not defined. Try adding 'track by $index' to your ng-repeat.